# Projection Optimization in Mongo Aggregation Framework

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

please look into this link for my question. http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-optimization.

It says optimization applies projection to head and returns only _id & amount. Now after projection  there is match on status field. But result of project doesn't have that fields, then how does it match on the result and filter them.

Comment: read it carefully : "The optimization phase applies the projection to the head of the pipeline such that only the _id and the amount fields return in the resulting documents from the $match stage as well."

Answer (score 1):

You actual question is a little "abstract" but to verify the point, what you really want to do for the **best** *optimization* is to [`$match`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) on your terms in the **first** stage of the pipeline:

```js
db.collection.aggreagte([

    // Match first
    { "$match": { "status": true } },

    // Rest of the pipeline

])
```

The main **"reason"** for that is you can **actually** *adresss* an index with that first stage. If you did that *later* in the pipeline, then you could **not**.

So try to optimize in this way, **always**.

Comment: That's got nothing to do with projection

Comment: @Sammaye Matching on an index **only** occurs at the **intial** stage of the pipeline. You cannot **match** with an **index** beyond that stage. Does that make this **clear** to you?

Comment: Samaya you got my question. @Neil, I think documentation says it will run projection, emit _id and amount and then match. Since output don't have "status" how it will filter the records.Does line "MongoDB applies the projection to the head of the pipeline" meant projection will be apply first or it will be applied after match.

Comment: @user3440520 Actually the reason for this was that the "match" will **only** be applied at the "head" or **first** stage, in this way. It is **best practice** to do so as I have pointed out. From the initial "comment" made on your question, you **need** to "project" the fields that you intend to use in any further pipeline stage. Otherwise, they are just **not** available to use *without* the *explicit* project. So you **really should** be "matching" **first**. Understand?